# Find last row containing data

Tags: vba, excel

I import RAW data into Excel. I want to create a macro to filter the data and to remove data that has been filtered out. The length of the RAW data report varies so the number of rows containing data changes. How do I make sure I filter all of the data?

```
Sub SF_FirstFilter()
'
' SF_FirstFilter Macro
' Step 6 (Step 41) - First Filter of RAW  Data
'
    Cells.Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
        ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$G$65000" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=Array( _
        "@E100A", "@T641A,@T766A", "@T766A"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
    Rows("84:65000").Select
     Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Selection.AutoFilter
End Sub
```

Comment: Is your issue getting all of the data to be autofiltered or selecting all of the data after the filter is applied?

Comment: The issue is getting all of the data to be autofiltered. The change you suggested works on one end but breaks the format of the work sheet. It tends to delete my col headers

Comment: That worked. I need more coffee. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for your deletion `rows(84:65000).select` you could try

`Range("A84:A65000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete`

```
Sub SF_FirstFilter()
'
' SF_FirstFilter Macro
' Step 6 (Step 41) - First Filter of RAW  Data
'
    Cells.Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
        ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$G$65000" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=Array( _
        "@E100A", "@T641A,@T766A", "@T766A"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
    Range("A84:A65000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    Selection.AutoFilter
End Sub
```

Comment: issue is getting all of the data to be autofiltered. The change you suggested works on one end but breaks the format of the work sheet. It tends to delete my col headers.

Comment: Check my solution again, what was happening is when you were selecting the rows for deletion, and then `selection.autofilter`, it had no data to filter. If you change it to this, the `cells.select` will always remain as `selection`. If your headers are deleted, change the range for deletion to not include the header